# Jersey deployment Error CDI

Tags: java, deployment, cdi, jersey-2.0

I have a problem deploying my jersey 2.0 web Applications, there is CDI deployment failure, Here the error log :

`org.glassfish.deployment.common.DeploymentException: CDI deployment failure:WELD-001408 <Br> Unsatisfied dependencies for type [IterableProvider<InjectionResolver<Object>>] with qualifiers [@Default] at injection point [[BackedAnnotatedParameter] Parameter 2 of [BackedAnnotatedConstructor] @Inject org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.JerseyClassAnalyzer(@Named ClassAnalyzer, IterableProvider<InjectionResolver<Object>>)]`

This error happens only sometimes. When it does I clean my project and restart my glassfish  until deployment succeeds but this takes too much time. I don't have any idea how to fix this problem permanently. Can anybody help me?